# Beautifulsoup4 picks up system default python2.6 and not my local python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am working in a system where I have no admin rights. I have my local environment where I have installed python3, pip3, and bs4. It seems that the default system python2.6 also has a beautifulsoup package installed. As a result, my Python code tries to pick up bs4 and ends up picking up the python2.6 one.

My code is:

```
try:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
except ImportError as err:
    print("BeautifulSoup is not installed. To install it use apt-get install python-bs4 or visit https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ for more information. \n OS error: {0}".format(err))
    raise
```

I am using pip to install bs4 with this command:

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4 
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /my-local-path/lib/python3.3/site-packages
```

Is there any way to force it to pick up the python3 one?

Comment: Did you just install bs4 by running `apt-get install python-bs4`?

Comment: Install `virtualenv` http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/
This will isolate all system wide python package anomaly.

Comment: What can't you use a virtualenv?

Comment: I am using pip to install bs4 with this command:
`$ pip3 install beautifulsoup4 `
`Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /my-local-path/lib/python3.3/site-packages`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the virtualenv proposal mootmoot. It not only solved my issue it also helped me find out that I actually needed python2.7 not 3.3 after all.

Try to leave an answer and I will accept at ones!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3 can't "pick up" python 2 package. You have not installed the correct bs4. For ubuntu, the package name is: [python3-bs4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python/python3-bs4).

Also your error message in `except` block is misleading as it points to python2 bs4, while the code is is python 3.

If you can't install a new package on your system, set up a [virtual-environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and install your dependencies by pip.

Comment: thanks for your message. I am using:
    `$ pip3 install beautifulsoup4
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /my-local-path/lib/python3.3/site-packages`

And it seems like it is working ok. Therefore I think I already have the python3 beautifoulsoup.

Comment: When I run my code though I am getting this error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my-local-path/Desktop/ROOT-Primer/scripts/Build_html.py", line 102, in <module>
    if child.name=='script':
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 667, in __getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, attr))
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'name'
`

Comment: It is solved by using virtualenv but thank you so much for noticing the wrong url. I forgot to change it after i moved the project to different bs4.